# Error opening a Android Xamarin Studio project on a mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to test out Xamarin Studio for converting over a current iOS project of mine.  Another developer at my company has given me an Android project that he made in Xamarin Studio that will share some common structure.

When I try to open the Android project on my Mac, Xamarin Studio gives me the following error:

```
(Load Failed) Project does not support framework 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.3'
```

I've been unable to find what actually causes this error, or what the solution may be.  Does anyone know what needs to be done to be able to load and view this project?

Answer (score 3):

I also got this issue when running one of the samples.

It seems that the resolution is to update Xamarin Studio and components to the latest versions, see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14134